# Range for int treated as string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have a project made in C#, MVC4 EF (data first).

In my Create view I have a number of numeric fields, for which I want to specify the allowed values, using Range. For some strange reason my numbers get treated as strings, which messes up the validation.

Lets take the field "LengthInch", for instance:
In the database it's an int.

In my View I have the code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LengthInch)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LengthInch)
```

and finally in my Metadata file (for the Model) I have the code:

```
[Range(0, 11, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
public Nullable<int> LengthInch { get; set; }
```

If I enter 0, 1, 10 or 11 in the field, everything is great but if I for instance enter 2 I get a validation error saying "Value for LengthInch must be between 0 and 11". The same goes for 3 to 9. So it seems like the numbers are treated as strings for some reason. Anyone having any idea?

Comment: I made an MVC 4 project, added a test class with just the property you are having issues with on it in the Models folder and created a strongly typed Create view for the test class.  I did not experience the bug you did.  I was able to enter values from 0-11, and received validation errors for any values above 11.

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare Was this with nullable types too?

Comment: @GertArnold I copied the exact code from his post

Comment: Does your project replace the default model binder or add any custom model binders?

Comment: 111 is not accepted. However 10000000001 is, so it seems like it's comparing strings.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy Well, I've added a "EF 5.x DbContext Generator for C#" and have all metadata in partial classes. That's where I have the definition for the Range-validation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Malcolm's point of a "new" project working pointed me in the right direction, thanks!  Seems that the jquery.validate guys did a bug fix push that addressed the [issue](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/pull/666).

```
        // convert the value to a number for number inputs, and for text for backwards compability
        // allows type="date" and others to be compared as strings
        if ( /min|max/.test( method ) && ( type === null || /number|range|text/.test( type ) ) ) {
            value = Number(value);
        }

        if ( value ) {
            rules[method] = value;
        } else if ( type === method && type !== 'range' ) {
            // exception: the jquery validate 'range' method
            // does not test for the html5 'range' type
            rules[method] = true;
        }
```

As soon as I did a nuget update for jqueryvalidation-1.11.1 it fixed the issue, welcome to JS package hell!

Comment: Since it was caused by a bug and this is the real solution, why not delete your other answer?

Comment: You have to put an `@` in front of his username or he'll never get the notification of your comment.

Comment: Interesting, I would think that it would be defaulted for an author to receive notifications of all comments, thanks @Sparky

Comment: @superdennis This solve your issue, if so could you mark it resolved?

Comment: @acg Sorry for the late reply. Yes, this solved the problem, thanks a lot!! Had jqueryvalidation-1.10.1 and updated to jqueryvalidation-1.11.1 and now it works like a charm!

Comment: Correction. Had jqueryvalidation-1.11.0 and updated to jqueryvalidation-1.11.1.